# using font awesome in svg text field with vuejs

Tags: svg, vuejs2, font-awesome

I am trying to use font-awesome in an svg text field. This is what I have tried:

Import the font into my vue project

```
import { faArrowLeftLong, faCog, faCopy, faFilter, faFilterSlash, faAngleRight, faAngleLeft, faCircleArrowDown, faCircleArrowUp, faTrash } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

library.add(faFilter, faCog, faCopy, faArrowLeftLong, faFilterSlash, faPlusCircle, faAngleLeft, faAngleRight, faTrash, faCircleArrowDown, faCircleArrowUp, faInputNumeric, faKey, faCheck, faCheckDouble, faAt, faAngleUp, faUpload, faCircleDashed)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

Then in my component I tried:

```
<div>
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'filter']" size="sm"/>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000">
        <text x="20" y="20" fill="gray" font-size="24px">
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'filter']" size="sm" />
        </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Now this does not seem to work, the icon within the text tag is not displayed. The one outside of the svg is visible.

Any idea would be welcome

Comment: What's not working? What are the errors? @Divyesh_08 Where is fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons in that *full-guide*?

Comment: The error is that is does not show the icon. If I use the same <font-awesome-icon> outside of the svg in a simple div I can see the icon. This is really due to the fact that it it inside the svg tag